# Adding a unique id to a column and including a value in the unique id from the same pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I'm assigning a unique id to a column on a pandas data frame.

I need to add a value from that dataframe to the unique id.

The column to use is `cxt`.

The following works except when I add in `cxt`, the `i` is then populated as the same value throughout the column, due to the looping effect.

How do I solve this?

```
    for i in range(len(gdf.index)): # give each feature a unique sequential ID
        i + 1
        i = str(i + 1)
        i=i.zfill(4)
        fid = sitecode_gbl + '_CXT' + gdf['cxt'] + '_FTR' + i
        feat.append(fid)
    featdf = pd.DataFrame(feat)
    gdf['FeatID'] = featdf[0]
```

Comment: Is possible add some data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use:

```
s = pd.Series(range(1, len(gdf.index)+1), index=gdf.index).astype(str).str.zfill(4)
gdf['FeatID'] = sitecode_gbl + '_CXT' + gdf['cxt'] + '_FTR' + s
```